# SENDER_ID_MISMATCH error when trying send notification to some devices

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting `SENDER_ID_MISMATCH` error when trying to send fcm notification.

Follwing is the error message i am gettin

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
>       {
>         "error": {
>           "code": 403,
>           "message": "SenderId mismatch",
>           "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
>           "details": [
>             {
>               "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
>               "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       }

Comment: According to the exception message, you don't have permissions to perform that action. However, could you elaborate a little more your question, please?

Comment: When we try to send fcm message to android devices, i am getting this error message